# Name the ScrollViewer in a GridView

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

What I'm trying to accomplish: If the user scrolls in the `GridView`, the background scrolls at a slower speed.

I Know I can do this, with transforms.

But my question is, how can I specify a name to the `ScrollViewer` of the `GridView`? So that i Can bind to the properties of the `ScrollViewer`.

My code for the GridView is very simple:

```
        <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HomeViewDataTemplateSelector}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false">
        <GridView.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/galleryArticleSwish.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </GridView.Background>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupTitle}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

I want to name it in XAML, I know i can get the `ScrollViewer`, through the visual tree and add some property on my ViewModel. But that's not a clean solution.

So how do I set the name of the `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't. Even if you extracted GridView control template and got the XAML that defines the ScrollViewer - it would most likely be a part of a different namescope and I am not even sure you can bind to its offset properties. The easiest option would probably be to find the ScrollViewer through visual tree and handle the ViewChanged events by scrolling your background, e.g. by updating the AlignmentX property of the ImageBrush.